# how to set UISegmentedControl text on left side

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want every segment text is alignment left, so I had try **UIControl contentHorizontalAlignment**, but it don't work, so I try to redraw **UISegmentedControl**, at beginning it will show at left, but if I choose one **segment**, the **segment** text will become *alignment centre*.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
      NSLog(@"z %s", __FUNCTION__);
      [super drawRect:rect];
      [self changeToLeft];
 }


-(void)changeToLeft
{
  for (UIView *segV in self.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subV in segV.subviews) {
        subV.frameX = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980424/text-alignment-issue-when-i-set-the-custom-font

Answer (score 4):

[image]

reduce/Change `ContentOffset -  x` =`-somepoints` it automatically comes on left side

[image]

additional reference of [apple Document for Segment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)

Answer (score 1):

[image: CHeck image for steps]

When I set the custom content offset in the storyboard and run the app, the text's offset remains same. Check video:[image: Video having proof]

If your problem remains unsolved, then please give more description. I am more than happy to solve your query.